# How to annotate an import declaration in Java?

Tags: java, import, annotations, package

I have a bunch of custom annotation, which I use in several occasions for various Java elements.

@Target annotation in the implementation of the custom annotations allow one to choose, where these custom annotations can be set in the Java code. The allowed ElementType's as @Target's parameter are the TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, PACKAGE, ANNOTATION_TYPE, LOCAL_VARIABLE and PARAMETER.

It seems to me that annotating an import declaration in Java is somehow not possible. Even when I don't declare specific types for the custom annotation and put one of them before an import declaration, I get the following error:

```
Multiple markers at this line
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
- Syntax error on token "@ (@)", "EOF" expected
```

Do you have any ideas regarding this issue? Is it even possible? If so, where might my mistake be? Thanks!

Comment: Annotations on import are not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import statements are just defining parser shortcuts. So they can't be annotated, because they aren't part of the abstract model of the code.

```
 import foo.Bar;

 ...
   Bar bar;
 ...
```

is exactly the same thing as

```
   foo.Bar bar;
```